# Red Copper Cookware

Tags: equipment

Just bought a new stove with glasstop.  I have a Red Copper (ceramic copper infused cookware) and not sure if it is recommended for the glass top.  I read that ceramic cookware not recommended and this is a 12" fry pan and the bottom is not smooth.

Comment: I don't know much about this new "red copper," so I'll just put this as a comment as others may know more about its exact properties.  But in general, as the question notes, ceramic cookware is NOT recommended on glass cooktops, as it can scratch the surface (particularly if bottom of pan isn't smooth). Also, a pan with an irregular bottom won't work particularly well on a flat-top stove, since heat will conduct irregularly compared to pans with flat bottoms that can make full contact.